# How to use conditional aggregation sql query in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am using Asp.Net MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6.2.0 with LINQ Extension Methods syntax.

I have 5 tables of variants, details below:

Product Table:

```
ProductID Name
    12    T-Shirt
```

Variant Table:

```
VariantID  ProductID  Name
    1         12      Size
    2         12      Color
    3         12      Material
```

VariantOption Table:

```
VariantOptionID  VariantID  VariantOptionName
      1              1            Small
      2              1            Medium
      3              2            Red
      4              2            Blue
      5              3            Cotton
      6              3            Lawn
```

Sku Table:

```
SkuID  ProductID  SKU              Price   Barcode
  1       12      Th-Sm-Red-Cot    120.00  345423
  2       12      Th-Sm-Red-Lon    130.00  345454
  3       12      Th-Sm-Blue-Cot   140.00  345451
  4       12      Th-Sm-Blue-Lon   150.00  345431
  5       12      Th-Md-Red-Cot    160.00  345472
  6       12      Th-Md-Red-Lon    170.00  345479
  7       12      Th-Md-Blue-Cot   180.00  654353
  8       12      Th-Md-Blue-Lon   190.00  254353
```

VariantOptionCombination Table:

```
VariantOptionID  SkuID
      1            1
      3            1
      5            1
      1            2
      3            2
      6            2
      1            3
      4            3
      5            3
      1            4
      4            4
      6            4
```

I want to show these tables records on web page as.

```
Size    Color  Material  Price   Sku
Small   Red    Cotton    120.00  345423
Small   Red    Lawn      130.00  345454
Small   Blue   Cotton    140.00  345451
Small   Blue   Lawn      150.00  345431
Medium  Red    Cotton    160.00  345472
Medium  Red    Lawn      170.00  345479
Medium  Blue   Cotton    180.00  654353
Medium  Blue   Lawn      190.00  254353
```

I am using this query to achieve the desire output. How can i translate this query in Entity Framework linq?

```
select  max(case when v.Name = 'Size' then vo.Name end) as Size,
    max(case when v.Name = 'Color' then vo.Name end) as Color,
    max(case when v.Name = 'Material' then vo.Name end) as Material,
    s.price
from ProductSKU s
join ProductVariantOptionCombination voc
on s.SkuID = voc.SkuId
join ProductVariantOption vo
on vo.VariantOptionId = voc.VariantOptionId  
join ProductVariant v
on v.VariantId = vo.VariantId
group by s.Price;
```

Comment: Assuming `vo.`max(vo.Name)` would pick the highest name lexicographically. Is that what you want?

Comment: If this query is complex and doesn't have linq equivalent, So can you help me to change the query?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
        var query = from s in YourDbContext.DbSet<ProductSKU>
            join voc in YourDbContext.DbSet<ProductVariantOptionCombination> on s.SkuID equals voc.SkuID
            join vo in YourDbContext.DbSet<ProductVariantOption> on voc.VariantOptionID equals vo.VariantOptionID
            join v in YourDbContext.DbSet<ProductVariant> on vo.VariantID equals v.VariantID
            group new {s,voc, vo, v} by s.Price
            into g
            select new
            {
                Price = g.Key,
                Size = g.Max(x => x.v.Name == "Size" ? x.vo.VariantOptionName : ""),
                Color = g.Max(x => x.v.Name == "Color" ? x.vo.VariantOptionName : ""),
                Material = g.Max(x => x.v.Name == "Material" ? x.vo.VariantOptionName : "")
            };
```

Comment: How can I query  a many-to-many relationship using Entity Framework code first and linq? The problem is that EF create automatically the relation table ProductVariantOptionCombination. So, I don't have it in my context?

Comment: So how can i use this YourDbContext.DbSet<ProductVariantOptionCombination> ?

Comment: Firstly, investigate entity framework and establish it in your application.

Comment: @Ahmed Hint: When you need help with EF query, include the relevant part of the model (classes, fluent configuration if any) rather than tables and columns.